# Design course/books for programmers?

Tags: mobile

I am programmer and I have an idea for a mobile app. I wanted to learn more about UI design and how to provide a better experience for the app user.
Are there any courses (preferably free) or books that I can learn design from?

Comment: Hello OP. I won't risk posting that as an answer, but look; [Microsoft Virtual Academy](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/) has several courses avaliable for free. Some books also. Depending on the language you're using, you can find some design tips there. If you're making a windows phone app, for instance, there are good stuff there on XAML that can help a lot.

Comment: And just to comment: I provided this link because MVA is a good starting point for programmers who want or need to make some design work. There is also design.windows.com, with general helpful guidelines, not just for windows.

Comment: Sorry, posted the wrong site of windows design. It's actually [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/hh779072](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/hh779072)